# Java and Hibernate - How to make OneToOne relation with SuperMappedClass and not an Entity

Tags: java, hibernate

I have tree Entities: `Client`, `ClientConfigurationA` and `ClientConfigurationB`.

I try to make something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "client")
    private ClientConfiguration configuration

    // some getter and setter
}

@MappedSuperClass
public class ClientConfiguration {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    protected Client client;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity(name = "CLIENT_CONF_A")
public class ClientConfigurationA extends ClientConfiguration { ... }

@Entity(name = "CLIENT_CONF_B")
public class ClientConfigurationB extends ClientConfiguration { ... }
```

But actually I can't define a OneToOne related to `MappedSuperClass` and not an Entity.

So what's the best way to implement this case ?

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611594/jpa-manytoone-mapping-with-inheritance) without succes.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Dont you mean `extends ClientConfiguration` and `private ClientConfiguration`? If not, its unclear what you want to do

Comment: That's what I mean. Sorry for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA ManyToOne mapping with Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611594/jpa-manytoone-mapping-with-inheritance)

Comment: This solution does not work. If i keep the `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance strategy it does not work at all, Hibernate can't find `CLIENT_CONF_A` or `CLIENT_CONF_B` Tables. If i set it to `TABLE_PER_CLASS` he find the tables but `configuration` from `Client` is null and `client` from `ClientConfiguration` is also null.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible and here's why:

When hibernate processes entities it needs to know what table to join with when resolving one to one relations.

The problem arise with `@MappedSuperClass` is that it doesn't define table, so multiple entities could be inherited from this class, each one having different table. Hibernate just couldn't know what table to join then.

If you want to have common super class, I suggest using an abstract `@Entity` class.

Comment: Ok, the fact is the only thing in common between the configurations is the foreign key to Client.
So if i can't define my join here, i'm going to have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts i finally succeeded.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "client")
    private ClientConfiguration configuration

    // some getter and setter
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
public abstract class ClientConfiguration {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    protected Client client;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity(name = "CLIENT_CONF_A")
public class ClientConfigurationA extends ClientConfiguration { ... }

@Entity(name = "CLIENT_CONF_B")
public class ClientConfigurationB extends ClientConfiguration { ... }
```